# How to insert a value into SQLAlchemy TIMESTAMP column

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, timestamp

I am trying to set value for timestamp column using SQLAlchemy, but I experience following error:

```
column "timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type numeric
```

My table looks as folows:

```
class SomeTable(db.Model):
    timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP)
```

Insertion try looks like this:

```
SomeTable(timestamp=time.time())
```

When I use datetime.now() instead of time.time() the record is inserted into the table but when I select it from the database it has following format:

```
2019-04-02 11:44:24.801046
```

So it looks like TIMESTAMP field does not store timestamp format.

Is it regular postgres behaviour? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is good, because next is correct:

```
Column('timestamp', TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
```

so by default you have `datetime.now()` there, it is about presentation

`datetime.now()` will give you `'2019-04-02 14:21:33.715782`

`datetime.now().isoformat()` will give you `'2019-04-02T14:31:09.071147'`

Check it with: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d0c6a/8

If you uncomment third insert you will get exact same exception as yours

Comment: Even better is using the sqlalchmey.func.now variable. It's better to use the database server's time.

Comment: I think that having `default=datetime.now()` will cause all your entries to have the same timestamp as that global `datetime.now()` will only be computed when the app is loaded. You probably need `datetime.now` instead. Or use the db function as Charles has suggested.